# .NET How to detect if DirectX 10 is supported?

Tags: .net, directx-10

I would like to find out from .NET code whether DirectX 10 is supported on the machine, preferably without using managed DirectX or XNA assemblies.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check which version of DirectX is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130764/check-which-version-of-directx-is-installed)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually very simple: If you are on Windows Vista / Server 2008 or later, you have "DirectX 10" the API. If you are on Windows Vista / Server 2008 Service Pack 1 or later, you have "DirectX 10.1" the API.

Neither of these answer the more useful question of: does the system have a DirectX 10 compatible video device and driver?

Really the only sure way to detect this is to create the device. If you can (a) find the `D3D10.DLL` and (b) a call to `D3D10CreateDevice` succeeds, then you have both the DirectX 10 API and a 10 compatible device.

Similarly, if you can (a) find the `D3D10_1.DLL` and (b) a call to `D3D10CreateDevice1` succeeds, then you have both the DirectX 10.1 API and a 10.0 or 10.1 compatible device.

DirectX 11.0 or later is always present on Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2 or later. Again, if you can (a) find the `D3D11.DLL` and (b) a call to `D3D11CreateDevice` succeeds, then you have both the DirectX 11 API and a 11 compatible device of some [feature level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx). The parameters to the [create device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device.aspx) will determine what feature levels are allowed. This procedure will also work to detect the case that you are on a Windows Vista / Server 2008 Service Pack 2 system with the [KB97644](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971644) update applied.

Once you have a `ID3D11Device` you can QueryInterface for `ID3D11Device1` to see if the system has DirectX 11.1 (Windows 8 / Server 2012 or Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2 with [KB2670838](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838), or `ID3D1Device2` to see if the system has DirectX 11.2 (Windows 8.1 / Server 2012 R2)

See [Direct3D 11 Deployment for Game Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416644.aspx)

The concept of "What version of DirectX is installed" is antiquated and dates back to the era of Windows 9x/ME. Running the "DirectX End-User Runtime Redist" does some stuff, but it *never* installs a new version of DirectX. See [Not So DirectSetup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx). The DirectX runtime is purely a function of OS patch level and has been since ~2004. See [What's in a version number?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/02/24/what-s-in-a-version-number.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 1):

To check DirectX10, we're actually calling the [D3DX10CheckVersion function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172639(v=vs.85).aspx) via platform invoke.

This requires presence of the D3DX10 DLLs in the C:\Windows\System32 or C:\Windows\SysWow64 folders (platform dependent). If these are not present, then you need to install the [DirectX10 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8109) on the target PC.

The actual support DirectX version / DirectX SDK version can be determined from the parameters to the P/Invoke call.

Here is the P/Invoke call:

```
// DX10 Supported Function
// See D3DX10CheckVersion http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172639(v=vs.85).aspx
[DllImport("d3dx10_43.dll", EntryPoint = "D3DX10CheckVersion", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = false)]
private static extern HResult D3DX10CheckVersion(
        uint D3DSdkVersion,
        uint D3DX10SdkVersion);

public enum HResult : int
{
    S_OK = 0x0000,
    S_FALSE = 0x0001,
    E_NOTIMPL = 0x0002,
    E_INVALIDARG = 0x0003,
    E_FAIL = 0x0004,
};

bool SupportsDirectX10()
{
    // Values taken from d3d10.h to check DirectX version
    const uint D3D10_SDK_VERSION = 29;
    const uint D3DX10_SDK_VERSION = 43;

    // Checks DirectX 10 GPU compatibility with the DirectX10 runtime
    // Assumes D3DX10 DLLs present in C:\Windows\System32 or
    // C:\Windows\SysWow64 folders (platform dependent)
    HResult hResult = D3DX10CheckVersion(D3D10_SDK_VERSION, D3DX10_SDK_VERSION);
    return hResult == HResult.S_OK; 
}
```

Comment: Nice, also seems it works for DirectX 11 with minor changes.

Comment: Just be advised you will need to check for presence of D3DX10_43.dll on target machine before calling this P/Invoke function. It's usually found in C:\Windows\System or System32 depending on platform version.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose calling this wrapped in try catch would do the trick right?

Comment: It'll work, but its far easier to just check for presence of D3DX10_43.dll in System or System32. 

Also note: not having these files does *not* mean that your computer doesn't support DirectX10. D3DX10_43.dll is part of the June 2010 DirectX SDK and must be redistributed to end-user PCs. Take a look at this link (http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17262/0/creating-and-deploying-applications-with-the-direct3d10rendersurface) to see how we solve this problem.

Comment: Another way of solving it without D3DX10_43.dll is to try to create a device using platform invoke and wrap in Try/Catch https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: What I am trying to do is to notify user during installation if DirectX 11 (I disassembled the dll to check for values) is usable beforehand so he/she knows if the game is gonna work or not. I want it to be robust. I mean code won't crash even if Directx is completely inexistent.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at the DirectX version installed on your machine using this key hive

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX
```

Here's a sample

```
[assembly: RegistryPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum,All = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")]
class Test
{
    public int DxLevel
    {
        get
        {
            using(RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX"))
            {
                string versionStr = key.GetValue("Version") as string;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(versionStr))
                {
                    var versionComponents = versionStr.Split('.');
                    if (versionComponents.Length > 1)
                    {
                        int directXLevel;
                        if (int.TryParse(versionComponents[1], out directXLevel))
                            return directXLevel;
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            } 
                     }
    }
}
```

Now if you want to know whether your video card supports DirectX, this is going to require XNA or DirectX interop.

Just a note, I couldn't test that code on my machine right now but that should get you started :)

Comment: Whhooops wrong version checking colde! Check the version # here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX#Releases

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm on Windows 7 but it's reporting version 9. DirectX 10 and 11 must use a different area of the registry.

Comment: That might be correct )not supporting DX10) unless the DirectX Runtime is installed https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8109

Comment: Registry keys are undocumented and highly unreliable.