# How to check that Firemonkey platform prerequisites are satisfied?

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

The documentation below outlines which prerequisites are required for running FMX applications.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites

I'm currently only interested in the Windows prerequisites. I could include this information on my product website, but it's quite technical for most people to check before downloading. I'd like to run a check when the application is first run and give a warning if the prerequisites are not satisfied. This will hopefully avoid users informing me of issues such as latency or rendering glitches that are caused by their system.

It would be useful if FMX had it's own functions for checking this (on whatever platform it's compiled for), but if not could anyone point me in the direction of some code to do this or perhaps an alternative solution, particularly with regards to the GPU?

One idea to avoid checking all prerequisites would be to render a kind of acid test image at first startup and compare it against a reference. It could also check that it renders within a given amount of time.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to write a VCL application (VCL has less requirements) to check for the OS version and for the presence of DirectX having pixel shader 5 or better. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130764/check-which-version-of-directx-is-installed).